# How to automatization process copying trouble ticket in two different CRM system?

Tags: java

We have two different separated system CRM. I need to know How to automatization process copying one trouble ticket from one system to another.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S00vi.jpg) - one system [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69c39.png) another system.

maybe write a script but I don't know how to do it.
With what language is this possible and how?

Comment: It is web or desktop?

Comment: it is desktop..

Comment: maybe, i use robot, it is simple and easy to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called RPA (Robotic Process Automation). There are a lot of tools and libraries to do that. For instance, you could use some paid options, such as Automation Anywhere and UiPath. There is also free software. I have successfully used Taskt. You could also use Robot Framework, Selenium, among many others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use robot, it is a simple and easy to understand

Code example

```
// Java program to demonstrate working of Robot 
// class. This program is for Windoes. It opens 
// notepad and types a message. 
import java.awt.AWTException; 
import java.awt.Robot; 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 
import java.io.*; 

public class robo 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
                           AWTException, InterruptedException 
    { 
        String command = "notepad.exe"; 
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
        run.exec(command); 
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(2000); 
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        { 
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        // Create an instance of Robot class 
        Robot robot = new Robot(); 

        // Press keys using robot. A gap of 
        // of 500 mili seconds is added after 
        // every key press 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_K); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_K); 
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S); 
    } 
}
```

Documentation link

[Robot java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)